# Does include_once for MySQL connection in 2 separate <?php ?> tags will connect only once?

Tags: php, include

In this case I use:

```
<?php 
include_once 'connect.php'; # connect with MySQL database
# some PHP code
?>

<!-- some HTML code -->

<?php 
# here PHP code wants to use MySQL connection opened before
?>
```

Should I even include_once in 2nd PHP tag?

Comment: No, It is enough to include it once on the top of your php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-include a file if it's within the same request/page.

Also, using `include_once` will prevent you from including files that have already been included.

You're free to use again variables and connection previously included by your `connect.php`

Answer (score 2):

The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

So if connect.php is included once it will not be included again

For example

```
<?php 
     include(a.php)  //it will include a.php
     include(b.php)  //it will include b.php
     include(a.php)  //it will include a.php again
?>

<?php 
     include_once(a.php)  //it will include a.php
     include_once(b.php)  //it will include b.php
     include_once(a.php)  //does nothing
?>
```

Comment: Your example is wrong. The second paragraph should make use of include_once. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you close a PHP tag, you don't close the Session, and the included code will remain available in all php tags you choose to open or close.

**Example**

```
- index.php
  - includes once connect.php
  - includes once foo.php
  - includes bar.php

- foo.php
  - Contains scope from connect.php

- bar.php
  - Contains scope from connect.php
  - Contains scope from foo.php
```

The only diffrence between include and include_once is if you're including the same file multiple times, it will still only be included once.

**Example Include**

```
<?php
    include ( 'connect.php' ); // Includes an evaluates code.
    include ( 'connect.php' ); // Includes an evaluates code.
    include ( 'connect.php' ); // Includes an evaluates code.
?>
```

**Example Include_once**

```
<?php
    include_once ( 'connect.php' ); // Includes an evaluates code.
    include_once ( 'connect.php' ); // Does nothing.
    include_once ( 'connect.php' ); // Does nothing.
?>
```

This is useful if your application uses modules, which then includes libraries. To make sure it doesn't include the same library many times, when it's only needed once, you use include_once.